# writing ATDDs for batch job

Tags: java, cucumber, batch-processing, atdd

I am trying to write ATDDs for a batch job. The job has the following scenario:
It checks the DB and if some event has been recorded 7 days back, it will pick up that event and reprocess. Here, 7 days is the pre-requirement to process it. While reprocessing, the system will interact with multiple services.
So, here I have to create this scenario through my ATDDs and want to verify if the job ran successfully.Means my ATDDs have to create specific data with the creation date as 1 week older.
I have enough experience with ATDDs with Cucumber+Java so want to work on same. Could someone give some idea whether it could be achieved?

Comment: Ofcourse this can be achieved. What have you tried so far?

Comment: When preparing this verification, ask yourself "What is the business value in doing this?" Start from there, the Why, before you dig into the technical details of How this will be done.

Comment: I am aware of the business value as I have to verify at the end that the data was created with creation date as 1 week older with other requirements and the batch service for which I am writing atdds should reprocess it and at the end, I need to verify it in DB to check it has been processed successfully

Comment: And what is the business value to the customer from (re)procesing this batch? Are his payments done, salary paid, invoice calculated, scores calculated? As a customer I don't care about a weekly batch job tbh... Can you provide example of the scenario?

Comment: When the batch runs successfully, business would know that the applications which were pending, have successfully been processed. Checking the end result is easy for me, but creating above scenario in batch job is what I am seeing complicated

Comment: @Marit Any thoughts?

Comment: Batch processing is not a business behavior. The end result of it might be. If you just want to make sure the batch is processed, you only need to monitor. If you want to test it is processed correctly, you might need to specify a small file per testcase and verify the result of processing that file.

Comment: "ATDDs" doesn't mean anything. Say "acceptance tests".